# What sort of analysis should I run to determine what day the difference between the treatments became significant

Tags: anova, excel

I have the following data:

[image]

Which shows how many days my sample was thermo-cycled, and the corresponding CFU/mL values per treatment (with the treatments being that some samples had water, some samples had glycerol, and some samples had F68 in them), so like after 3 days, the sample with water had a CFU/mL value of 1.13E06 etc.

I am trying to determine on what days the differences between the 3 treatments is significant at an alpha level of .05 and I'm not quite sure what the best analysis would be? Also any tips on running the analysis in excel would be appreciated.